# source code in tickSize d3.js v4

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to understand the tickSize documentation in d3.js v4:

> axis.tickSize([size]) <>
>
> If size is specified, sets the inner and outer tick size to the
>   specified value and returns the axis. If size is not specified,
>   returns the current inner tick size, which defaults to 6.

When I check the source code I get this:

```
axis.tickSize = function(_) {
    return arguments.length ? (tickSizeInner = tickSizeOuter = +_, axis) : tickSizeInner;
  };
```

I don't really understand what is going on.

- Whats is `_` doing as a parameter of the function?
- What is this part of the code `(tickSizeInner = tickSizeOuter = +_, axis)` doing?

Source: https://github.com/d3/d3-axis/blob/master/src/axis.js#L140

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method will return the current value for `tickSizeInner` if there are no arguments provided for the method. Alternatively it will set the `tickSizeInner` and `tickSizeOuter` variables if an argument is provided.

This is done in this line:

```
return arguments.length ? (tickSizeInner = tickSizeOuter = +_, axis) : tickSizeInner;
```

Which is a use of the [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) which is a shorthand method for this:

```
if(arguments.length)  {
    tickSizeInner = tickSizeOuter = +_; return axis 
}
else {
   return tickSizeInner; 
}
```

*See also [this question, King's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14758672/proper-use-of-a-comma-in-javascript-ternary-operator) or [this doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) regarding commas with ternary operations.*

Here's a stripped down version of the function logic:

```js
function tick(_) {
    return arguments.length ? _ : 6;
  };
  
console.log(tick())
console.log(tick(4))
```

The beauty in this sort of approach is your getter and setter method is one and the same.

Note that zero in javascript is falsey, take a look at the lines below (undefined is also falsey, included for comparison, see [also this](https://www.google.ca/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=jrMoWb_sHOiM8Qf1wLKIDw&gws_rd=ssl#q=falsey%20values%20in%20javascript)):

```js
if(0) { console.log("true"); }
else { console.log("false"); }

if(1) { console.log("true"); }
else { console.log("false"); }

if(undefined){ console.log("true"); }
else { console.log("false"); }
```

So, if no argument is passed, then the current tick size is returned. If an argument is passed (underscore is a valid variable name, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661197/what-characters-are-valid-for-javascript-variable-names)), then it is forced into a number (`+_`) and set to equal the tick sizes (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133770/how-do-i-convert-a-string-into-an-integer-in-javascript)'s top answer for converting strings to numbers).

Here's an example of forcing variables to integers:

```js
var a = "1";
var b = "2";

console.log(a+b);

a = +a;
b = +b;

console.log(a+b);
```

And lastly, you can assign values to multiple variables in the manner shown in the code. For example:

```js
var a = 0;
var b = 0;

a = b = 5;

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```